# Définition of density in metric space.

Tags: general-topology

My definition of $A\subset B$ dense in $B$ if $$\forall x_0\in B, \forall \varepsilon >0, \mathcal B(x_0 ,\varepsilon )\cap A\neq \emptyset.$$
In this definition, shouldn't we rather take $$\mathcal B(x_0,\varepsilon )\setminus \{x_0\}\neq\emptyset \ \ ?$$

Comment: I changed $B(a,b)$ in $\mathcal B(a,b)$ for balls because you already used $B$ for set, so the notation can be confusion.

Comment: @Surb: thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

No, the definition you gave is correct. Take for example $\mathbb N$ with discrete metric. Of course $\mathbb N$ is dense in it self. If you use $\mathcal B(x_0,\varepsilon )\setminus \{x_0\}$ instead of $\mathcal B(x_0,\varepsilon )$, then when $\varepsilon <1$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, you'll get $$\mathcal B(n,\varepsilon )\setminus \{n\}=\emptyset,$$
what contradict density.

Comment: Good example. I didn't think about that (I had in mind $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$...)

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the definition given,
$$
    \forall x_0 \in B,\ \forall \varepsilon > 0,\ \exists a \in A,\ d(x_0,a) < \varepsilon
$$
where $d$ is the metric.  If $x_0 \in A$ already, then that's fine.  But what's more interesting is that points of $B \setminus A$ also have points of $A$ arbitrarily close to them.

Comment: A topology doesn't have to be metrizable for density to make sense.

Comment: @nomen: as the title says : we are in metric spaces.

Comment: Wups my mistake.